# Select from a drop down menu

Tags: vba, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to run a set of queries in a web page. The initial query defines if the DropDownList1 has more than one option. Selecting additional option reloads the web form. 
When I run the following part nothing in the drop down list get changed. If I skip the ...FireEvent... line the values of the drop down menu are changing during the loop, but the web form is not reloading and the initial values are returned for all the list elements.

```
Set dd1 = doc.getElementById("DropDownList1")
If dd1.Options.Length > 1 Then
  For Each opt In dd1.Options
    doc.getElementById("DropDownList1").Focus
    doc.getElementById("DropDownList1").selectedIndex = opt.Index
    doc.getElementById("DropDownList1").FireEvent ("onchange")

    ''copy the elements' values in excel sheet
  next opt
end if
```

Do you have an idea what I'm missing?

This is the whole code:

```
Sub addresses()

Dim evt As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim IE As Object
Dim Form As Object
Dim ID As Object
Dim Name As Object
Dim address As Object
Dim CForm As Object
Dim Code As Object
Dim Activity As Object
Dim NKD_2007 As Object
Dim NKD_2002 As Object
Dim dd1 As Object
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim sh, exp As String

sh = "Sheet6" ''read sheet
exp = "Sheet7" ''export sheet

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "https://www.dzs.hr/app/kalendar/RPSByCode.aspx"
While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
 DoEvents
Wend
j = 2
 Set doc = IE.Document
 Set Form = doc.forms("form1")
 Set ID = doc.getElementById("TextBox1")
 ID.Value = "01487434" ''ID VALUE
 Form.submit
 While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4
  DoEvents
 Wend
 On Error Resume Next
 Set Name = doc.getElementById("DataList1_ctl01_NazivLbl")
 Set address = doc.getElementById("DataList1_ctl01_AdresaLbl")
 Set CForm = doc.getElementById("DataList1_ctl01_PUONazivLbl")
 Set Code = doc.getElementById("DataList1_ctl01_Label1")
 Set Activity = doc.getElementById("DataList1_ctl01_Label2")
 Set NKD_2007 = doc.getElementById("DataList1_ctl01_Label3")
 Set NKD_2002 = doc.getElementById("DataList1_ctl01_Label4")
 Set dd1 = doc.getElementById("DropDownList1")

 ''filling the table
 Sheets(exp).Cells(j, 2) = Name.innertext
 Sheets(exp).Cells(j, 3) = address.innertext
 Sheets(exp).Cells(j, 4) = CForm.innertext
 Sheets(exp).Cells(j, 5) = Code.innertext
 Sheets(exp).Cells(j, 6) = Activity.innertext
 Sheets(exp).Cells(j, 7) = NKD_2007.innertext
 Sheets(exp).Cells(j, 8) = NKD_2002.innertext

 j = j + 1

 If dd1.Options.Length > 1 Then
  For Each opt In dd1.Options
     On Error Resume Next         
     IE.Document.getElementById("DropDownList1").selectedIndex = opt.Index
     IE.Document.getElementById("DropDownList1").FireEvent ("onchange")

     Set Name = IE.Document.getElementById("DataList2_ctl01_NazivLbl")
     Set address = doc.getElementById("DataList2_ctl01_AdresaLbl")
     Set Activity = doc.getElementById("DataList2_ctl01_Label2")
     Set NKD_2007 = doc.getElementById("DataList2_ctl01_Label3")
     Set NKD_2002 = doc.getElementById("DataList2_ctl01_Label4")

     Sheets(exp).Cells(j, 2) = Name.innertext
     Sheets(exp).Cells(j, 3) = address.innertext
     Sheets(exp).Cells(j, 4) = CForm.innertext
     Sheets(exp).Cells(j, 5) = Code.innertext
     Sheets(exp).Cells(j, 6) = Activity.innertext
     Sheets(exp).Cells(j, 7) = NKD_2007.innertext
     Sheets(exp).Cells(j, 8) = NKD_2002.innertext

     j = j + 1
  Next opt
 End If

 Set doc = Nothing
 Set Form = Nothing
 Set Name = Nothing
 Set address = Nothing
 Set CForm = Nothing
 Set Code = Nothing
 Set Activity = Nothing
 Set NKD_2007 = Nothing
 Set NKD_2002 = Nothing

IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: _"Do you have an idea what I'm missing?"_ ... Yes. Your html code.

Comment: This is the web page: https://www.dzs.hr/app/kalendar/RPSByCode.aspx  .This code for the first field (01487434) results in more than 1 options for the drop down menu.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. This row didn't work properly:  *IE.Document.getElementById("DropDownList1").selectedIndex = opt.Index*

I don't know why buth the object dd1 loses its elements after FireEvent or form submit. Using *IE.Document.getElementById("DropDownList1").Value=string_from_previously_assigned_array* and re-submitting the form resulted in working code.